# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'server' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I use the variable server on my print statement I get this error.

> File
> "/Users/c0deninja/projects/gsecurity/modules/fetch_requests.py", line
> 40, in get_headers
> print(f"{Fore.MAGENTA}[+] {Fore.CYAN}-{Fore.WHITE} SERVER: {Fore.GREEN}{server}") UnboundLocalError: local variable 'server'
> referenced before assignment

Also the error only appears on certain websites, maybe when there's no server header it starts getting buggy?

```
def get_headers(url: str) -> str:
    sessions = requests.Session()
    try:
        res = sessions.get(url, verify=False, headers=header)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            for value, desc in res.headers.items():
                if value == "Server":
                    server = desc
                if value  == "Via":
                    via = desc
        print(f"{Fore.MAGENTA}[+] {Fore.CYAN}-{Fore.WHITE} SERVER: {Fore.GREEN}{server}")
        print(f"{Fore.MAGENTA}[+] {Fore.CYAN}-{Fore.WHITE} VIA: {Fore.GREEN}{via}")
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema:
        print("Please use https://www.target.com")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Check the target URL and try again\n")
```

Comment: Have you declared your variable "Server" anywhere before ?

Comment: You can move each `print` call under the appropriate `if` clause -- print server info if the `value` is "Server" and print via in the other `if`

Comment: @tromgy that took care of the error but since the print statement is now under the for loops it just iterates the SERVER: and VIA: output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I fixed it, what I did was create an empty list outside of the loop and append the output there and then print it.

```
def get_headers(url: str) -> str:
    sessions = requests.Session()
    server_output = []
    via_output = []
    try:
        res = sessions.get(url, verify=False, headers=header)
        if res.status_code == 200:
            for value, desc in res.headers.items():
                if value == "Server":
                    server_output.append(desc)
                else:
                    pass
                if value  == "Via":
                    via_output.append(desc)
                else:
                    pass
            print(f"{Fore.MAGENTA}[+] {Fore.CYAN}-{Fore.WHITE} SERVER: {Fore.GREEN}{', '.join(map(str,server_output))}")
            print(f"{Fore.MAGENTA}[+] {Fore.CYAN}-{Fore.WHITE} VIA: {Fore.GREEN}{', '.join(map(str,via_output))}")
            
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema:
        print("Please use https://www.target.com")
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print("Check the target URL and try again\n")
```